# diff-refine-hunk with unified diff

Tags: diff, vc, diff-mode

### Problem

Some versions of `diff` (notably, `busybox diff` in every build of BusyBox I've seen) only produce "unified" diff format output, they don't produce the output that GNU `diff` produces by default.

When I try to run `diff-refine-hunk` in a `vc-diff` buffer (`git` repository, if that matters), it fails, and prints the following error in the minibuffer:

> Unexpected patch hunk header: --- /tmp/diff*

(Where the asterisk is some number of randomly generated characters, obviously.)

### Question

Is there a way I can get `diff-refine-hunk` to handle a `diff-command` whose output is always just unified diffs?

### Detailed Example

#### Steps

I start with this dummy file, version-controlled in git:

```
00 00
11 11
22 22
33 33
55 55
66 66
77 77
88 88
99 99
bb bb
cc cc
dd dd
ee ee
ff ff
```

I edit/replace it with this, and save it to disk (but don't stage/commit in git):

```
00 00
22 22
33 33
44 44
55 55
66 66
7x 77
88 x8
99 99
aa aa
bx bb
dd dd
ex ee
ff ff
```

Run `vc-diff` with `C-x v =`, so far so good.

Run `diff-refine-hunk` with `C-c C-b`. And if the invoked diff command is BusyBox `diff` (or GNU `diff` with the `-u` option) it fails with the "Unexpected patch hunk header" error. If the diff command is just regular GNU `diff` without the default output, it works fine.

### Example Output `emacs` sees from various `diff`s

From what I've gathered since I first posted this, `diff-refine-hunk` runs `diff-command` on several temporary files (one for each hunk?), and parses the output from each to refine the hunks. What follows are the output `diff-command` produces for one of those hunks (the one with the "77" and "88" 'words'). In the case of the failure cases, this hunk is the one `diff-refine-hunk` stops at (in the success case, it keeps calling `diff-command` on other hunks).

#### GNU `diff` output

When called by `diff-refine-hunk` in the setup above, this isthe output of GNU `diff` (normal, successful case):

```
2,3c2,3
< 77
< 77
---
> 7
> x
12,13c12,13
< 88
< 88
---
> x
> 8
```

#### GNU `diff -u` output

When called by `diff-refine-hunk` in the setup above, this is the output of GNU `diff -u` (failure case):

```
--- /tmp/diff122272NoN  2016-11-26 00:43:54.796744201 +0000
+++ /tmp/diff222272ayT  2016-11-26 00:43:54.832744689 +0000
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 -
-77
-77
+7
+x

 77
 77
@@ -9,6 +9,6 @@
 88
 88

-88
-88
+x
+8
```

#### BusyBox `diff` output

When called by `diff-refine-hunk` in the setup above, this is the output of Busybox `diff` (failure case - same output except no datetime in header):

```
--- /tmp/diff122272bly
+++ /tmp/diff222272NvB
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 -
-77
-77
+7
+x

 77
 77
@@ -9,6 +9,6 @@
 88
 88

-88
-88
+x
+8
```

#### How I captured the above outputs

I created a script like this and pointed `diff-command` in emacs to it to test each variant and capture the outputs of each background run of diff (unlike a prior edit to this question, this script captures each `diff-command` run in a separate file, since `diff-refine-hunk` can call the diff backend program multiple times.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec busybox diff "$@" | tee "`mktemp /tmp/busybox_diff.XXXXXX`"
#exec diff -u "$@" | tee "`mktemp /tmp/gnu_diff-u.XXXXXX`"
#exec diff "$@" | tee "`mktemp /tmp/gnu_diff.XXXXXX`"
```

### Question - Re-Worded

Is there a way to get `diff-refine-hunk` to work correctly when the underlying diff command that it calls in the background on temporary files always produces output in that unified format?

Comment: I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` and give an actual problematic diff sample.  The author of *diff-mode* (yours truly) mostly uses unified diffs, so this format should actually work better rather than worse.

Comment: @Stefan I suspect you might have not understood exactly the problem I am describing: the issue is when the underlying program pointed to by `diff-command` on the system always produces unified diff output. So it's got nothing to do with the diff format you see/use within emacs, but everything to do with the diff format emacs parses under-the-covers to figure out the "refined" diffs.

Comment: @Stefan At any rate, I have added a thorough example with hopefully enough information for you or someone to help out. If you still want me to file a bug report through `report-emacs-bug` with the above information or anything else, I will do so as well.

Comment: @Stefan I've yet to submit a bug report (mostly because I doubt I'd have an easy time getting the issue understood in the first place - perhaps you could help with that when/if we figure out if you misunderstood what I meant initially). In the meantime, I've posted my own answer of how I solved the issue for me, perhaps it'll make things clearer, and lead a way to a more elegant emacs-only solution.

Comment: A very quick look at `diff-refine-hunk` shows that it tries to detect the diff format by calling `diff-hunk-style` which in turn uses a fairly complex regexp `diff-hunk-header-re`. Is that not detecting the hunks from the busybox diff output as being in the unified style?

Comment: @mtraceur: Indeed I had mis-understood the problem.  It's not a bug in diff-mode, but rather either a "misfeature" of busybox's diff, or a missing functionality in the refinement code (which is shared between diff-mode and smerge-mode).

Comment: @phils Yep, to my inexperienced eyes, it looks like `diff-hunk-header-re` would do a fine job of getting the correct header, but it never gets to that point, because diff-refine-hunk doesn't account for the two header lines that a unified diff starts with (before any individual hunk header line). I saw partial success when I stripped those two lines off with a simple pipeline through `tail`, but there was some other mis-behavior if I recall correctly. I can re-test that scenario if you'd like.

Comment: @Stefan I suspect BusyBox won't budge: BusyBox's whole point is minimalist utilities: Supporting an additional diff format when unified diff provides all the information one might in principle need is not something I'd presume they'd want to support (but I don't have any intimate insight into the direction of that project). I would be happy to submit a patch for the refinement code, but I am a complete novice to the emacs codebase.

Comment: Ah, that specific error `Unexpected patch hunk header: --- /tmp/diff*` appears to come from either `smerge-refine-subst` (seems likely) or `smerge-apply-resolution-patch` (identical code, presumably not the trigger in this case). A grep says no other elisp produces that error message. It is indeed parsing the output of a call to `diff-command` with no `-u` argument, and consequently expecting non-unified output, as you ascertained. I think there was some confusion over *where* the error was coming from, though.

Comment: @mtraceur: Indeed, I don't think Busybox would be interested in this use case (and since they support my favorite format, I think they made a pretty good decision).  I see one option tho: supplement diff-mode with a diff-unified->normal (which isn't very high priority, but would be mildly useful in itself), and then use that in the refinement code when the output is in unified format.

Answer (score 1):

Documenting my own crude solution for now, in case it helps anyone. I'll happily accept another answer with a better solution.

My solution took the form of two parts:

1. Wrapper shell script around BusyBox's `diff`, converting its unified output into traditional/"normal" output. (It's now in one of the directories in my PATH as `bnudiff`. I put it on GitHub it [here](https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/bnudiff/blob/master/bnudiff) in case anyone wants to look).
2. Emacs function advice around `smerge-refine-subst` (I initially wrapped `diff-refine-hunk`, but then learned from the comments that the actual refining function is the smerge one, and is presumably shared by one or more other modes as well) to make it use `bnudiff` instead of `diff` as the backend `diff-command`:

   ```
   (defun smerge-refine-subst-wrapper (smerge-refine-subst-real &rest arguments)
    (let ((diff-command "bnudiff"))
     (apply smerge-refine-subst-real arguments)
    )
   )
   (advice-add 'smerge-refine-subst :around #'smerge-refine-subst-wrapper)
   ```

This works perfectly (though I'm not in love with the inherently kludgey nature of it).